# logic or math on numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, contest-math

There are 200 fishes in a pond, 99% of which were red. How many red fishes must be removed to make the percentage of red fishes are 98%?
Thanks in advace

Comment: Any ideas? What did you try?

Comment: 99% red means, 198 are red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total number of red fishes $= \frac {99}{100}  \times 200 =198  $

Number of red fishes removed $=x$

New total number of fishes $= 200 - x$

New total number of red fishes = $198 - x$

Now, relate to the new percentage, i.e, 98%

> New number of red fishes $= \frac {98}{100}  \times (200-x) =198-x  $

## ↑SPOILERS↓

> x = 100